# Show this set is a base for $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be the collection of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $\{x : \alpha \leq x < \beta\}$.  Is $S$ a base for a topology for the set $\mathbb{R}?$

I'm a little confused as to how the metric comes into play in this question.  Don't I need to show that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ then $y$ is in some set that is $S$.

Comment: What metric? There is no metric involved anywhere.

Comment: You need to check that this set covers the reals (easy) and that it satisfies a certain intersection property (slightly harder). There is no metric given.

Comment: The topology is called the Sorgenfrey line, also called the lower-limit topology. It cannot be defined by a metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $x \in [x,x+1\rangle \in S$.

For $[\alpha, \beta\rangle, [\gamma, \delta\rangle \in S$ we have

$$S \ni \big[\max\{\alpha, \gamma\}, \min\{\beta, \delta\}\big\rangle = [\alpha, \beta\rangle \cap [\gamma, \delta\rangle$$

Thus, $S$ is a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Check the conditions:

Do these sets $[\alpha, \beta)$ cover $\mathbb{R}$? If $[a,b)$ and $[c,d)$ intersect and $x \in [a,b) \cap [c,d)$ does there exist some $[\alpha, \beta)$ such that $x \in [\alpha, \beta) \subseteq [a,b) \cap [c,d)$?

A metric is not relevant, it's not asked whether this is a base for the usual metric topology, but for some other topology (note that the supposed base elements are not open in the usual topology).